# how can i get an object to move with the mouse horizontally but has a set y position in python

Tags: python, pygame

im trying to replicate the spaceship in the arcade game galaga. the spaceship needs to move slower than the mouse but still follows it. this is what i have so far and im not sure where to go from here. please help 
keep in mind im new to programming so im sure this is hard to look at.

```
import pygame
import math
pygame.display.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

#fireSnd = pygame.mixer.Sound()
#pygame.mixer.music.load()
#pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
x1 = 400
x2 = 405
x3 = 395
point1 = (x1,585)
point2 =(x2,600)
point3 = (x3,600)
SpaceShip = (point1,point2,point3)
Hdir = 0

done = False

while not done:
    # Step1. Erase the screen
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # Step2. Update

    # Step3. Process variables
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            done = True
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        x,y = event.pos
    # Step4. Drawing
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (255,0,0) ,(SpaceShip), 0)
    pygame.display.flip()



pygame.display.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have your ship move left at x rate if the mouse is left of it, and right at x rate if the mouse is to the right of it.

To get mouse position:

```
mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

And you may want to change the way that you draw your spaceship. Right now you have designated a triangle with point1, point2, and point3. It doesn't change. Let's do something like this:

```
spaceshipPos = [400]

Spaceship = ((spaceshipPos[0],585),(spaceshipPos[0] + 5,600),(spaceshipPos[0] - 5,600))
```

This just takes the spaceship's position and give the location of each of the triangle's points.

```
while True: # game loop

    if spaceshipPos[0] > mousePos[0]:  # if the mouse is to the left, move left
        spaceshipPos[0] -= 5
    elif spaceshipPos[0] < mousePos[1]:  # if the mouse is to the right, move right
        spaceshipPos[0] += 5

    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (255,0,0), Spaceship, 0)
```

So your full code would be:

```
import pygame
import math
pygame.display.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

#fireSnd = pygame.mixer.Sound()
#pygame.mixer.music.load()
#pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

Hdir = 0

moveRate = 1

spaceshipPos = [400]

done = False

while not done:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            done = True

    mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if spaceshipPos[0] > mousePos[0]:  # if the mouse is to the left, move left
        spaceshipPos[0] -= moveRate

    elif spaceshipPos[0] < mousePos[0]:  # if the mouse is to the right, move right
        spaceshipPos[0] += moveRate

    elif spaceshipPos[0] == mousePos[0]:
        pass

    Spaceship = ((spaceshipPos[0],585),(spaceshipPos[0] + 5,600),(spaceshipPos[0] - 5,600))
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (255,0,0) ,(Spaceship), 0)

    pygame.display.flip()



pygame.display.quit()
```